# Is there a native way to do resource by resource authorization with Auth0 or JWTs more generally?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, auth0

Wondering if there is a standard way to implement authorization for specific resources (e.g., web pages) by user.

Was thinking of setting up scopes based on https://example.com/articles/:id

such that if a given user had paid for access to a specific article they would be granted access to that endpoint.

Auth0 has an option for doing stuff like that for arbitrary APIs in Applications->APIs "Define APIs that you can consume from your authorized applications." Which it seems like grants an access token to specified users, which you can then scope by resource (I think).

Only concern is this doesnt really seem scalable if we have, say, 100,000 articles and I'm not exactly sure how to generate these scopes on the fly as articles are created and purchased.

Is there a simpler way of setting up these permissions just using JWTs and without having to go through the Auth0 interface, or is there something I can write as an Auth0 rule?

Answer (score 0):

This is something best managed in your API code, since the resources a user can read is not something the Authorization Server needs to know about.

**JWT ACCESS TOKEN**

This can include the following fields of interest:

| Field | Description |
| --- | --- |
| sub | A generated ID for the user |
| userID | The ID for the user in your API's own data |
| scope | A business area and allowed privileges, eg `pages_read` |

**API AUTHORIZATION**

The API would need to first check that the token has a valid scope for the resource. Then it would typically perform a database filter based on the userID.

Aim also for a setup where authorization is easy to change as business rules evolve.

**CLAIMS**

A JWT can also include claims, eg a claim could be an array of `Location IDs`. When resource IDs are highly volatile or very large, as in your example, they are not usually included in the JWT.

See [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) for more about claims and real world API authorization.